# How to get what percentage of screen Is covered by sprite mask in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a scratch effect using line renderer and sprite masks. I want to calculate what percentage is scratched on the screen. How can I do it?

Or else any alternative solution?

Comment: Your question kinda reads as _["where they want to start, and where they want to end, but there are way too many pieces to fill in"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223458/284550)_ and if so might be considered too broad.  Consider adding more information about how you would like your problem solved, perhaps with a code sample of what you have already tried.  Good luck!